# ansible playbook cannot apply, giving host unreachable error

Tags: kubernetes, ansible-inventory, ssh

I'm completely new to ansible and I'm having a hard time with it. I have an inventory.yml file which is as the following:

**EDIT: changed my inventory.yml now looks as follows**
inventory.yml:

```
[master]
master1 ansible_host=192.168.56.2 ansible_port=2222 ansible_user=deploy ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant ansible_become_pass=vagrant apt_key_master=https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg

[worker]
worker1 ansible_host=192.168.56.3 ansible_port=2200 ansible_user=deploy ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant ansible_become_pass=vagrant apt_key_worker=https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
```

also I have a playbook called kube-repos.yml which is as follows:

**EDIT: changed kube-repos.yml now looks as follows:**
kube-repos.yml:

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:

  - name: add Kubernetes apt-key
    apt_key:
      url: "{{ apt_key_master }}"
      state: present

  - name: add Kubernetes' APT repository
    apt_repository:
      repo: deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
      state: present
```

when I apply my ansible playbook using `ansible-playbook kube-repos.yml` I get the following error:

```
fatal: [master1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [worker1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).", "unreachable": true}
```

I see my problem is getting proper authentication ansible to ssh into the host vm's.
I am able to do `vagrant ssh master` and `vagrant ssh worker` and get into my vm's perfectly fine but when I apply the playbook and if I use the command `ansible all -m ping` I get the UNREACHABLE error. I am trying to setup a simple kubernetes cluster consisting of one master and one worker node.

I am at a loss now because I have read the ansible documentation but still cannot figure out how to correct this error. So I feel like I have no choice but to ask on here. I hope someone is kind enough to help me out and thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
after the changes suggested by @mikequentel I have the following error:

```
fatal: [worker1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 192.168.56.3 port 2200: Connection refused", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [master1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 192.168.56.2 port 2222: Connection refused", "unreachable": true}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following for each Vagrant machine you want Ansible to work with...in this example, using the machine `master1`:

1. Do `vagrant ssh-config > vagrant-ssh`
2. Enter content from `vagrant-ssh` into your `~/.ssh/config`, modifying it as needed, like this example for some machine named `master1`:

```
Host master1
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/myname/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

3. Then, in your hosts (inventory) file, include the login information needed by Ansible, for each machine:

```
master1 ansible_host=master1 ansible_port=2222 ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant ansible_become_pass=vagrant
```

or also use IP address for `ansible_host`:

```
master1 ansible_host=192.168.56.2 ansible_port=2222 ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant ansible_become_pass=vagrant
```

Comment: thanks again I'm now getting connection refused error instead of permission denied :/

Comment: @user2152012 are you able to ssh into each machine you want to reach with Ansible? Each would need SSH daemon running (if these are *nix machines). Like, should be able to do `ssh machine1`

Comment: when I ```ssh worker1``` I get ```ssh: Could not resolve hostname worker1: Temporary failure in name resolution``` so I can't

Comment: Maybe need to specify the IP address for `worker1`, so: `worker1 ansible_host=192.168.56.3 ansible_port=<this might be different than master1?> ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant ansible_become_pass=vagrant`

Comment: yh that is what I have done still no luck I edit the files in the question to show how they look now.